# JSON.serialize results in System.JSONException: Salesforce System Error

Tags: apex, json, javascript-remoting, remote-action, gack

This is just a test page. I want to send Javascript object into Remote Method and save it as JSON string, but it keeps failing with this error. Any help is appreciated.

Visualforce page

```
<apex:page controller="TestController" applyBodyTag="false">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function buildFormData() {
                var form = {};
                form.config = {};
                form.config.pages = [];
                var page = {};
                page.rows = [];
                var row = {name: 'Account Row'};
                page.rows.push(row);
                row = {name: 'Contact Row'};
                page.rows.push(row);
                form.config.pages.push(page);

                form.config.baseobjects = [];
                var baseObj = {name: 'Contact'};
                form.config.baseobjects.push(baseObj);
                baseObj = {name: 'Account'};
                form.config.baseobjects.push(baseObj);
                return form;
            }

            function saveForm(){
                var formData = buildFormData();
                Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.TestController.saveForm}', 
                    formData, function(result, event) {
                        if(event.status) {
                            console.log(result);
                        } else {
                            alert('Error: ' + event.message);
                        }
                    }, {buffer: false, escape: false, timeout: 30000}
                );
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h2>Send object and get json string.</h2>
            <br />
            <button onclick="saveForm()">Save Form</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</apex:page>
```

Apex Controller

```
global with sharing class TestController {

    @RemoteAction
    global static String saveForm(FormData data) {
        System.debug('## data ' + data.config);
        // it crashes on JSON.serialize
        return JSON.serialize(data.config);
    }

    global class FormData {
        public Map<String, Object> config {get; set;}

        public FormData() {
            config = new Map<String, Object>();
        }
    }
}
```

**FATAL_ERROR|System.JSONException: Salesforce System Error: 823227431-4348 (717264018) (717264018)**

```
    34.0 APEX_CODE,DEBUG;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
12:24:15.064 (64561656)|EXECUTION_STARTED
12:24:15.064 (64624655)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|06690000005iyPH|VFRemote: TestController invoke(saveForm)
12:24:15.064 (64670374)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true
12:24:15.066 (66479728)|METHOD_ENTRY|[1]|01p900000072RHd|TestController.TestController()
12:24:15.066 (66578736)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|false
12:24:15.066 (66600814)|SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT|false
12:24:15.066 (66634140)|METHOD_EXIT|[1]|TestController
12:24:15.066 (66662920)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|false
12:24:15.067 (67044839)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[5]|String.valueOf(Object)
12:24:15.067 (67514273)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[5]|String.valueOf(Object)
12:24:15.067 (67578792)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[5]|System.debug(ANY)
12:24:15.067 (67781555)|USER_DEBUG|[5]|DEBUG|## data FormData:[config={baseobjects=[{name=Contact}, {name=Account}], pages=[{rows=[{name=Account Row}, {name=Contact Row}]}]}]
12:24:15.067 (67812570)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[5]|System.debug(ANY)
12:24:15.067 (67897852)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[6]|TestController.FormData.__sfdc_config()
12:24:15.067 (67963920)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[6]|TestController.FormData.__sfdc_config()
12:24:15.068 (68111137)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[6]|System.JSON.serialize(Object)
12:24:15.076 (76852763)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[6]|System.JSON.serialize(Object)
12:24:15.076 (76889916)|SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT|false
12:24:15.077 (77131149)|FATAL_ERROR|System.JSONException: Salesforce System Error: 2043493233-942 (717264018) (717264018)

(System Code)
Class.TestController.saveForm: line 6, column 1
12:24:15.077 (77204398)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|VFRemote: TestController invoke(saveForm)
12:24:15.079 (79569009)|EXECUTION_FINISHED
```

On trying to serialize the `Map` property from `FormData` class

**{baseobjects=[{name=Contact}, {name=Account}], pages=[{rows=[{name=Account Row}, {name=Contact Row}]}]}**

Comment: Can you add a debug so we can see the output?

Comment: @AdamMichaelDaw I have added debug log. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Sort of. We know the serialization is what's failing. Can you pass the "data" to debug so we can see what it's trying to serialize?

Comment: i'm not seeing any quotes, double or single. that seems weird for me for strings...

Comment: @jagmohan - Your code that you posted does not match what the debug log is showing. Please update your code with the exact code that is causing the error. In fact, **the code you posted works just fine** so it is something else you are doing

Comment: @jagmohan The error message "2043493233-942 (717264018)" is a [GACK code](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/02/gack.html). You could try raising this with support to find the underlying cause.

Comment: @Eric Its not working for me. I have uploaded the same code here.

Comment: indeed a GACK error code. have it escalated to Salesforce.

Comment: @AdamMichaelDaw Sorry for confusion, but, the log shows toString version of Map.

Comment: @jagmohan - Well that brings context into it..At least we now know what you are trying to serialize

Comment: I really do not think you need to serialize because afaik, there is automatic serialization. You can mark return type of saveform as Map<String,Object> and in the end return data.config.

Comment: @manjit_singh I want to convert that Map<String, Object> into String and save it in Salesforce.

Comment: Okay, if you wan to save it, you can use JSONGenerator to convert it to a string. JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true); gen.writeObject(data.config); return gen.getAsString(); **OR** you can pass a string directly from VF remoting by using  JSON.stringify(formData) instead of formData in **Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction** and make the input param for saveform method in contorller as string. [JSON Stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: @manjit_singh Thanks! JSONGenerator seems to be solution. Just curious as to why JSON.serialize crashes.